# React Factory Function

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I found this code online, however, I am a beginner to React and I cannot understand it. What does this code do? Does it clone a component?

I'm very sorry for the very basic question. Help would be insanely appreciated!

```
const Factory = function ({
  React,
  thing,
  isActive,
  addThing,
  deleteThing,
  name,
  description,
} = {}) {

  const Thing = function (props) {
    return {
      propTypes: {
        thing: React.PropTypes.object,
        isActive: React.PropTypes.bool,
        addThing: React.PropTypes.func,
        deleteThing: React.PropTypes.func,
        name: React.PropType.string,
        description: React.PropType.string,
      },

      props,

      render () {

        return (
          <Card>
          <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{ this.props.name }</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{ this.props.description }</Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        );
      }
    };
  };

  return Thing;

};

export default Factory;
```

Comment: Can you share the link for this article

Answer (score 0):

propTypes is used for validation.

Here `Factory` is a functional component which will receive below arguments

`React`,`thing`,`isActive`,`addThing`,`deleteThing`, `name`, `description`

and then you are validating the data type of each of the argument passed using `propTypes`
Like `isActive` should be boolean. If not satisfied it will throw an error.

Then it renders an JSX element with name and description and also returns a reference of `Thing`